# Creating a "try it" code editor- any security issues?

Tags: javascript, security

I'm creating a simple "try it yourself" code editor like [the one found](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_content_noquote) on W3schools. Looking at the source, it seems all that one does is use JavaScript's `document.write()` command to write whatever is entered into the textarea on the left into the iframe on the right, without any sanitation:

```
function submitTryit() {
  var text = document.getElementById("textareaCode").value;
  var ifr = document.createElement("iframe");
  ifr.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
  ifr.setAttribute("id", "iframeResult");  
  document.getElementById("iframewrapper").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("iframewrapper").appendChild(ifr);
  var ifrw = (ifr.contentWindow) ? ifr.contentWindow : (ifr.contentDocument.document) ? ifr.contentDocument.document : ifr.contentDocument;
  ifrw.document.open();
  ifrw.document.write(text);  
  ifrw.document.close();
}
```

Is that secure in itself, or am I missing something inside the [w3school's editor](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_content_noquote) that does something more for security's sake?

Thanks,

Comment: Secure against what? Please do not confuse W3C with w3schools (though I am sure w3schools fully intends you to be confused).

Comment: Secure against what? A user can always hack himself.

Comment: The various forms of `eval` are only an issue if a) other users can control the evaled value b) there is anything to harm, like a login

Comment: I should clarify, the editor would be posted online for all visitors to use, so security against potential malicious users.

Comment: But... It's running on their browser.

Answer (score 0):

If that javascript is not persisted in such a way that it can render to browsers of users other than its authors, you should be fine. Otherwise you are creating a platform that can be used to propagate XSS worms. Just allowing a user to execute arbitrary javascript on their own page is no less secure than that most modern browsers having a debugging console that lets a user execute javascript.

Comment: "Otherwise you are creating a platform that can be used to propagate XSS worms." --- how so? It is plenty of various jsfiddle-like sites.

Comment: True, there are plenty of sites like that. I don't know if they make any attempts to prevent this sort of thing, but I haven't seen anything publicized about them being used in attacks. With that being said, any site that can run javascript can test your browser for vulnerable plugins and attempt to exploit them.

Also, it's worth noting that most sites like jsfiddle use an iframe to prevent the javascript from interfering with the outer frame.

Edit: you might find this interesting. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackhole_exploit_kit